# SQL Help - pull counts of purchase and join ids

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. I want to count the number of people who bought products A,B,C in a certain period of time. Products can be bought multiple times. So each person ID may be counted in two or more columns depending on his purchase behavior in a given timeframe.
2. Then I need to pull the actual person IDs for each product and their mail id from a different table.

[image: Purchase Table]

[image: MailID table]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed. Also, [please avoid pictures of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584)

Comment: Just added two images of data tables into question. Could figure out how to attach it. Let me know if this is sufficient. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add it into the question as text. So take it out of the comment (and remove the comment), and then into the question please. Text is best by far, so people don't have to re-type everything. Graphics only = much smaller chance of people giving it a try.

Comment: What have you tried so far???  I don't see any queries.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a test question but here it goes:

For #1 I'm assuming you only want to count each person once even if they got the product multiple times, you do that with a distinct count. So the code would look like this:

```
select [Product Purchase], count(distinct [Person ID]) from [Purchase Table] where [Time Stamp] between <start> and <end>
```

For #2, it seems like a join:

```
select distinct [Product Purchase], pt.[Person ID], [Mail ID] from [Purchase Table] pt join [MailID Table] mt on pt.[Person ID] = mt.[PersonID]
```

I hope I'm not doing your homework for you though.

Comment: I assure you that it's not for test or homework. I'm trying to add a new skill to my resume. So I'm trying out various scenarios to practice sql.

Comment: here's the query I tried but coming back with error.

Comment: select count (distinct personID) , count(CASE WHEN lower (product_purchace) like ‘A%’) as A count (CASE WHEN lower (product_purchace) like ‘B%) as B from purchase_table where (timestamp between '2017-08-01%' and '2017-12-31%')